# Django. получение значения из поля со списком. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_category_display'

Tags: django, views

Как обработать ситуацию, если нужно извлечь значение ключа из категории (получается), а когда нет объявлений чтобы не выскакивала ошибка **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_category_display'**. (если нет товаров с данной категорией)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product

def by_category(request, category_name):
    products = Product.objects.filter(category=category_name)
    category = Product.objects.filter(category=category_name).first().get_category_display()
    context = {'products': products, 'category': category}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Может, просто `if products` перед тем как доставать первый элемент?

Comment: @nomnoms12 получается другая ошибка **local variable 'category' referenced before assignment**. Нужно чтобы категория выводилась даже если нет товаров. {{ category }} в шаблоне

Comment: @HaZcker , что вам мешает отфильтровать по категориям `Category.objects.get(name=category_name)`?

Comment: @Александр в модели category выбирается в поле через **choises=CATEGORYES**, а сами категории выглядят примерно так 
CATEGORYES = (
    ('s', 'category1'),
    ('b', 'category2'),
        ...
)

Comment: @HaZcker , так а если нет товаров, какую категорию выводить по дефолту?

Answer (score 0):

Замените строку `category = Product.objects.filter(category=category_name).first().get_category_display()`

на этот код:

```
first_category = Product.objects.filter(category=category_name).first()
if first_category:
    category = first_category.get_category_display()
```

Comment: получилось так же как в ответе к **nomnoms12**. Решил не очень красиво, своеобразным костылём, сейчас напишу как

Answer (score 0):

**всё что выше def by_category - подключаемый файл**

```
CATEGORYES = {
        's': 'category1',
        'b': 'category2',
            #...
    }
    def get_category(key):
        return CATEGORYES[key]

    def by_category(request, category_name):
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=category_name)
        category = get_category(category_name)
        context = {'products': products, 'category': category}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```